# How to register in the screen the arrows pressed on the keyboard?

Tags: python, windows, view, console

I try to make in python a counter of how many times the arrows on the keyboard have been pressed and show it to me on the screen, I do not try to do anything else so as not to misinterpret it, I want to count how many times the arrows have been pressed because I need it to move accurately some elements in word.

My source:

```
from pynput import keyboard as kb

def pulsa(tecla):
    print('Se ha pulsado la tecla ' + str(tecla))

with kb.Listener(pulsa) as escuchador:
    escuchador.join()
```

Comment: Show us the code you're currently working with. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry, corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

count = defaultdict(int)

def pulsa(tecla):
    print('Se ha pulsado la tecla ' + str(tecla))
    count[tecla] += 1
```

(I assume a `tecla` is hashable -- if not use `count[str(tecla)] += 1`.)

The effect of defaultdict is, 1st time we see e.g. up_arrow,
it will pretend there was already a count of `0` up_arrow's.
And then it just increments from there,
each time you press the up arrow.

---

You may find it convenient to use a debug print within the keystroke handler:

```
from pprint import pp

def pulsa(tecla):
    count[tecla] += 1
    pp(count)
```